# Passing a list of functions to a component through props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Let's say you have the following functions (or more):

```
function hasValue(element) {
    return (element.value && element.value.length);
}

function isLongerThan(element, minLength){
    return element.value.length > minLength;
}
```

**How would you try to pass these as a list of functions to a component through props?**

I've attempted something like:

```
<MyInputComponent runThese={[hasValue, isLongerThan]} />
```

Or

```
<MyInputComponent runThese={[() => hasValue(), () => isLongerThan()]} />
```

But the functions require the `element` parameter (which is a child node of MyComponent), along with other parameters to work.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: When you attempted the first solution, how did you figure it wouldn't work that way? `if (this.props.runThese[0](el)) ...` should work fine, since those functions aren't accessing anything outside their scope. A function's parameters are set at the time you're calling it; `"the functions require the element parameter"` doesn't make any sense.

Comment: `[hasValue, isLongerThan]` is fine, you just have to call the functions properly.

Comment: @ChrisG @FelixKing How would you pass `minLength` to `isLongerThan` with the first solution? Remember the `runThese` array may contain a varied assortment of functions all requiring slightly different parameters.

Comment: You need to know the position of the function inside the array. Then just call `this.props.runThese[1](el, 8)`. There are better solutions though, like moving the function to your Component's class definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following syntax

```
<MyInputComponent runThese={[(element) => hasValue(element), (element) => isLongerThan(element, 23)]} />
```

Here, you can pass element from child component like following

```
const {runThese : [hasValue, isLongerThan]} = this.props;
hasValue('el');
isLongerThan('el');
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example showing how you can pass functions to a component and run them. We're passing the 2 functions, `hasValue` and `isLongerThan` in an array. We then setup an `onChange` event listener to call the functions in the array. If all the input functions pass (return `true`) we set the state of the input to `valid`.

In the case of `isLongerThan`, we'll create a function to return a function, so we can set the `minLength` value.

Run the snippet below, then enter some values into the input. You'll see `false` logged until the input value has a length greater than 3.

```js
function hasValue(element) {
  return (element.value && element.value.length);
}

function isLongerThan(minLength) {
  return function(element) {
    return element.value.length > minLength;
  }
}


class MyInputComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      valid: false
    }
  }

  handleChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({
      valid: this.props.runThese.every(func => func(event.currentTarget))
    })
    
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <input type="text" onChange={this.handleChange} className={(this.state.valid ? 'valid': 'invalid' )}/>
    )
  }
}


ReactDOM.render( <MyInputComponent runThese={[hasValue, isLongerThan(3)]} />, document.getElementById("app"))
```

```css
input {
  outline: none;
}

.valid {
  border: 3px solid green;

}

.invalid {
  border: 3px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```